# Apache webroot icons not loading

Tags: php, apache, icons

I know this is a silly question, but I would like to know why it is happening so.

I am using wamp server version 2.1. While viewing directories in localhost, the images beside the files are not getting loaded. Refer image below. On inspect of the image, I see it fails to load `/icons/folder.gif`, where can I find those images and how to load them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, you've either removed or moved the icons folder or you've modified a file that points to that folder somewhere on your machine...

The icons folder should reside in: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache(version)\

Here are the icons: http://jordanarsenault.com/icons.zip

If they are not already there, put them there.

Comment: @Jordan Arsenault thnx for the reply. I see the icons folder in my `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17`. I have all the images there but phpmyadmin is not able to load them.

Comment: the screenshot you have supplied does not appear to be phpmyadmin...it looks to me like a web server root.

Comment: @Jordan Arsenault yea.. ill modify the question

Comment: phpmyadmin is the web based graphical user interface associated with your mysql installation...

when did you start seeing these issues? what kind of changes did you make to your configuration to make this happen?

Comment: if you inspect the location of the broken images, they read "icons/folder.gif"... that's dandy, but if the pictures aren't rendering, something suggests you've botched the directory leading up to that directory; by either modifying the name of the directory itself, or changing a file that points to it.

Comment: have you modified httpd.conf at all? You can access httpd.conf by clicking WAMP in your system tray -> Apache -> httpd.conf...

There should be a line:

ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.17"

make sure the slashes are forward and not back as you've used in your above comment...

Comment: @Jordan Arsenault i have not changed anything as far as i remember. I have installed wamp on a brand new system.

Comment: @Jordan Arsenault I have checked httpd.conf, ServerRoot reads this `c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.17` which is exactly what you have mentioned.

Comment: also verify that the lines ~178 and ~205 in httpd.conf are correctly pointing to the location of your web root (both forward slashed directories)... because your line numbers might not be identical to mine, One defines _DocumentRoot_, the other is the directory wrapped in a <Directory> tag.

Comment: @Jordan Arsenault this is what i have at those lines. `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"` and `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` which are pointing correctly.

Comment: it is forbidden by Apache if rewrite_module  is on , im looking for solution also

Answer (score 8):

Step 1, Edit "httpd-autoindex.conf" file like;

```
Alias /icons/ "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/icons/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.2/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Step 2, remove first "#" characters from "httpd.conf" file in

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

lines

Step 3, restart all services from wamp try icon

Comment: Use   "Order deny,allow
    Allow from all",  instead of "Require all granted". It doesn't seem to work on Apache 2.2.22

Comment: thanks.. path to the icon folders in httpd-autoindex.conf were not correct... you steps were really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

it is pointing to wrong dir in

C:\wamp\bin\apache\YOUR_VERSION\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf

```
Alias /icons/ "/httpd-2.2-x64/icons/"

<Directory "/httpd-2.2-x64/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

should be

```
Alias /icons/ "icons/"

<Directory "icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

restart server

Comment: thanks.. path to the icon folders in httpd-autoindex.conf were not correct... you steps were helpfull

Answer (score 0):

jsut find the "httpd-autoindex.conf" file from c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra  folder from apache(your version) folder

find this line "Directives controlling the display of server-generated directory listings".

below this line there will be a address like this "C:/Apache2.2/icons/"    (little difference may be there) (2 times)

edit it like this "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons/"    (into your directory not the same)

(be careful to use your directory address not the same as above)

it will work...

or check this link and find the answer   http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,27544,27861#REPLY